# if condition in haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, haml, custom-data-attribute

I want to set a :data attr if a condition is met. In this case a user should have a role. So it's a boolean statement. Let me give an example.

```
 - @data = 'contract-confirm'

 .create_button= link_to 'Something', new_some_path(@customer), :class => 'btn btn-success', :'data' => @data ? 'contract' : nil
 .clearer
```

So I know this might look strange but I want to set a data attribute if customer is labeled and then hook js to that data attr. That part works. What does not work is that now I'm setting the attribute always. So even in the case that customer does not have the role the js gets hooked. I know that I am not explicitly indicating at all the role here. I have a @customer.role? but I cant seem to incorporate it properply. I managed it before with an if else statement but then with a lot of duplication which I'm not so fund of. Any tips?

Comment: hm, I cannot fully understand what you are trying to do here: you always set @data variable to some string, and then test that variable with ternary operator: well, it will always evaluate to true as you have just assigned your variable to a string.
Or is there some additional code between the first and third lines?

Comment: Hmm I see your point. Well what I would like to do is set data attribute if customer is in role if not in role set it to nil. Do ypu understand what I mean?

Comment: Will this work?
link_to 'Something', ... , :data => @customer.role? ? 'contract' : nil

Comment: It does actually. Thank you. Was really staring blind on that one. Thx for the input. I you post as answer I can mark it as the correct it one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this piece of code:

```
link_to 'Something', ... , :data => @customer.role? ? 'contract' : nil
```

haml won't include *nil* attributes, so it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace **:'data' => @data ? 'contract' : nil** with **:'data' => 'contract' if @data**.
I checked it and next code:

```
- @data_present = true
= link_to 'Something', root_path, :class => 'btn', :'data' => ('test' if @data_present)
```

renders to:

```
<a href="/" class="btn" data="test">Something</a>
```

And code without **- @data_present = true** renders to:

```
<a href="/" class="btn">Something</a>
```

Comment: Thx for answer. Well it stills sets it to true always.